# LinkedIn Javascript API broken in Firefox 35.01 & Safari 8.03

Tags: javascript, firefox, linkedin-api

I am using the Javascript API from Linkedin.

Until Firefox 35.01, the sign-in button for LinkedIn worked like a charm. It works in all browsers except Firefox 35.01 and Safari 8.03 (tested in OSX, Windows 7) and Firefox Developer Edition 37a2 as of today (2 Feb update).

The button is not visible anymore on load as before. If I call the API with a custom script, an error is thrown (as expected).

The following error is thrown in Firebug:
**"Error: IN is not defined"**

The API is loaded properly with 'status 200 OK'.

I can't even log in the LinkedIn developer website itself anymore! same error. This suggests that the API is broken as of the latest Firefox release.

Any update from LinkedIn on how to resolve this?

Comment: Use http://mozilla.github.io/mozregression/ to find out exactly what broke it and what fixed it again. Create a bugzilla bug and report your findings there.

Comment: Thanks. I will try my best with the moz regression. Today it works again in the Nightly 38.0a1, but not in Beta 36 or Developer. This possible solution still leaves Safari 8.03 open. I would expect the LinkedIn Api team to follow these nightly builds to see how their product behaves, but apparently they are miles behind and leave browser compatibility testing to open source developers waisting their precious evening hours.